Vercel is not calling my API even though it is uploaded successfully
I'm facing an issue with my Next.js application that works correctly in my local development environment but runs into problems when deployed on Vercel. Specifically, after redeploying the app on Vercel, everything works initially. However, the /api/prompt endpoint stops functioning as expected, even though other parts of the app (like user authentication) continue to work.
I see Vercel logs indicating successful database connections and API requests, but the /api/prompt fetch fails silently, and no data is fetched. This behavior is inconsistent: the site works after redeployment but breaks after some time.
Here’s how I’m fetching my data:
const fetchPosts = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("/api/prompt", { cache: "no-store" });
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log("Fetched Posts:", data); // Log fetched data
    setAllPosts(data);
};

Troubleshooting Steps Taken
Checked the API Endpoint: I confirmed that the /api/prompt endpoint works locally but not on Vercel, so I examined the fetch request in my application to ensure it was correctly set up.
Re-deployed the Application: I re-deployed the app on Vercel, which temporarily resolved the issue, but then it broke again over time.
Examined Vercel Logs: I looked at the Vercel logs to identify any errors or issues with the API calls. I noticed that the /api/prompt endpoint wasn't being called at all.
Tested Database Connectivity: I verified that my database connection string and settings were correct, ensuring that there were no issues with connecting to MongoDB from Vercel.
Debugged the Fetch Logic: I added console logs in my fetch functions to trace the flow of data and check what was being returned.
Checked Session Management: I looked into potential issues with session handling in the app, especially since I encountered a 504 error related to the session fetch.
Considered Environmental Differences: I thought about any discrepancies between my local setup and the production environment on Vercel that could affect the application’s behavior.
Explored Serverless Function Limits: I researched the limitations of serverless functions on Vercel, including timeout issues and caching behavior, to see if that could be impacting the API response.
Despite these attempts, the problem persists, indicating that there might be deeper issues with the Vercel deployment itself rather than my code or database.

You need to give us a minimal repro at least. Impossible to answer without the info provided.
